# How to avoid 'Parameters are not used' in xgboost?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I am using gridsearchcv and xgboost for data prediction, but there is a serious overfitting in my results, so I would like to include early in the parameters_ Stopping parameters were processed.

```
pipeline_xgb = Pipeline([
    ('data_processing', data_processor),
    ('model', xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=250,
                               objective='reg:squarederror',
                               min_split_loss=0.01,
                               eval_metric=mean_squared_error,
                               ))
])

xgb_param = {
    'model__learning_rate': [0.05],
    'model__max_depth': [10],
    'model__subsample': [0.8],
    'model__reg_lambda': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    'model__verbose': [False]，
    'model__model__early_stopping_rounds':[10]
    
}

xgb_gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline_xgb,
                      param_grid=xgb_param,
                      cv=5,
                      n_jobs=-1,
                      verbose=4,
                      return_train_score=True,
                      scoring=['neg_mean_absolute_error', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'r2'],
                      refit='neg_mean_squared_error',
                      error_score='raise'
                      )

xgb_gs.fit(X_train, y_train, ,
           model__model__eval_set=eval_set)

cv_results = pd.DataFrame(xgb_gs.cv_results_)
best_model = xgb_gs.best_estimator_
```

but the results showed:

```
Parameters: { "model__early_stopping_rounds", "model__verbose" } are not used.
```

How can I solve this warning?

Except for xgb_ Param, I also tried to transfer this set of parameters to xgb.XGBRegister(), but it's also the same warning. when I put these parameters in xgb_gs.fit(), I got an error